# Promise and deferred objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, deferred

I have the following which I took from a really good answer on here, stitching two suggested methods together but I can't see how to get the code working correctly.

```
var animals = ['mouse', 'newt', 'shrew', 'grasshopper', 'frog', 'hedgehog'];

$('#s1text1').delay(dur).fadeOut(dur).promise()
.then(function() {
    return $('#s1text2').fadeIn(dur).promise();
})
.then(function() {
    var p = new $.Deferred().resolve();
    return $.each(animals, function(i, animal) {
        p = p.then(function() {
            return $('.' + animal).fadeIn(defaultDur, function() {
                animateAnimalGroup(animal);
            }).promise();
        });
    })
    .then(function() {
        return $('#s1text2').fadeOut(dur).promise();
    })
    .then(function() {
        return $('#s1text3').fadeIn(dur).promise();
    })
    .then(function() {
        return $('#s1text4').fadeIn(dur).promise();
    });
```

Any help/advice would be much appreciated. A good tutorial/article on this would be really useful as well if anyone knows of one, I've read a few bits but am struggling to get my head around it.

Comment: It would be very helpful to actually describe the problem.  What is it that isn't working and how is it supposed to work?

Comment: Where are you closing the `.then` in the `p = p.then` ?

Comment: What is the point of `var p = new $.Deferred().resolve();`?  Why create a deferred and immediately resolve it?  Why not just create a deferred that you then resolve later?  Or better yet, why even create your own when you can just use the promises from the jQuery animations?

Comment: @jfriend00 in order to get an empty resolved promise later used to queue operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to return the result of `$.each`, you want to return the `p` promise that you have accumulated in the loop. Also, it's missing closing brackets:

```
.then(function() {
    var p = new $.Deferred().resolve();
    $.each(animals, function(i, animal) {
        p = p.then(function() {
            …
        });
    })
    return p;
})
.then(…)
```

Answer (score 0):

Bigwigal, you may be interested in an alternative approach involving `array.reduce()`, to build your `.then()` chains without the need for an explicit loop or explicit assignment/reassignment of generated promises.

```
//Data
var animals = ['mouse', 'newt', 'shrew', 'grasshopper', 'frog', 'hedgehog'],
    fades1 = [
        {id:'s1text1', delay:dur, action:'fadeOut'},
        {id:'s1text2', delay:0, action:'fadeIn'}
    ],
    fades2 = [
        {id:'s1text2', delay:0, action:'fadeOut'},
        {id:'s1text3', delay:0, action:'fadeIn'},
        {id:'s1text4', delay:0, action:'fadeIn'}
    ];

//Phase 1 (initial fades)
fades1.reduce(function(promise, item) {
    return promise.then(function() {
        return $('#' + item.id).delay(item.delay)[item.action](dur).promise();
    });
}, $.when()).then(function() {
    //Phase 2 (animal fades)
    return animals.reduce(function(promise, animal) {
        return promise.then(function() {
            return $('.' + animal).fadeIn(defaultDur).promise().then(function() {
                return animateAnimalGroup(animal);//you probably want a return here but not necessarily, depending on the visual effect you want.
            });
        });
    }, $.when());
}).then(function() {
    //Phase 3 (final fades)
    return fades2.reduce(function(promise, item) {
        return promise.then(function() {
            return $('#' + item.id).delay(item.delay)[item.action](dur).promise();
        });
    }, $.when());
});
```

What you now have is a hard-coded, generalised three-phase animation pattern, the detail of which is **data-driven**. To change the detail, simply modify the arrays, `animals`, `fades1` and `fades2`.

This approach can be useful, not so much in the final result, but during development when you will probably change your mind a dozen times before being satisfied.

You could probably go further and do the whole thing with one array and one `.reduce()` but the data structure and the code may become unwieldy.

I agree that the `.reduce()` pattern is not the most readable on the planet, but it's well worth going through the pain barrier of learning it (as I have done only recently).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain this, I really do appreciate it. I can definitely see the advantages of this approach.

Comment: I just tried to vote this up but I don't have the rep unfortunately. Thanks again though, very useful.

Comment: Bigwigal, there are some nonsenses in StackOverflow. Goodness knows why you need rep before you can upvote. You can always come back later when you have gained a few more points.